# Difficulty renaming timeline markers

Tags: timeline, marker

I'm new to working with timeline [`Markers`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/markers.html). Frequently, when I try to rename a
marker (by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>
), it defaults to a previous name, (in the example:
“Pull to home”). If I change this object name, it has no effect on the selected marker, nor any other marker on the timeline. Why?

Currently, the solution is to repeatedly select and unselect the marker until, for reasons I don't understand, it suddenly becomes amenable to editing. Any suggestions? Blender 3.2.2, Windows 11

[image: example]

Comment: that's weird, I suppose you press Enter?

Comment: Yep, I press enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender is sensitive to where you have placed the mouse pointer. **To rename the marker you have to move it into the marker area** at the bottom of the timeline. Otherwise, it will rename the selected object ("Pull to home" in your example, "Cube" in my example).

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's what's going on. That explains how one of my objects got renamed to "Pull to home." Thanks Blunder! :)